# Are scrolls tied to a magic Tradition?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

Pathfinder 2e scrolls have precious little information, as far as I can tell. The information [on them as Equipment](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=640) is simply

> The traits for a scroll vary based on the spell it contains. A scroll always has the consumable, magical, and scroll traits, plus the traits of the spell stored on it.

and the [trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=140) provides even less

> A scroll contains a single spell you can cast without a spell slot.

What I'm confused about is "plus the traits of the spell stored on it." Does this include the magic Tradition? Do you need to meet that Tradition in order to cast the spell (or use Trick Magic Item)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it in another section.

> To Cast a Spell from a scroll, the spell must appear on your spell list. Because you’re the one Casting the Spell, use your spell attack roll and spell DC. **The spell also gains the appropriate trait** for your tradition (arcane, divine, occult, or primal).

So the scroll itself does not have a Tradition, but gains it when used.